# Ruby on Rails, Sprockets::FileNotFound, Error compiling CSS asset

Tags: ruby, sprockets

I am trying to install Ruby on Rails on my Mac. When I run "Rails s" it runs fine, but when I go to "localhost:3000" in my browser I get the following error:

```
Error Compiling CSS asset
Sprockets::FileNotFound: Couldn't find file 'unify/sliders/revolution/bg-text.png'
(in /Users/user1/project/app/assets/stylesheet/unify/plugins.css.erb)

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:153:in `resolve'
```

My gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

gem 'meta-tags'

gem 'pg'
group :production do
gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
# gem 'better_errors'
# gem 'binding_of_caller'
# gem 'pry'
# gem 'sprockets_better_errors'
gem 'rails-dev-tweaks', '~> 1.1'
gem 'thin'
end

gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails' #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :github => 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'unicorn'
gem 'community_engine', :git => 'https://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git', :branch => :rails4
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 1.6.0'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'json'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'authlogic', '3.4.0'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 2.2.1'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'underscore-rails'
gem 'twitter', '~> 5.9.0'
gem 'feedjira', :git => 'https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira.git'
gem 'nokogiri', '>= 1.5'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'bootstrap-kaminari-views'
gem 'factual-api'
gem 'activerecord-import'
gem 'treat', github: 'louismullie/treat'
gem 'engtagger'
gem 'jqcloud-rails'
gem 'embedly'
gem 'yaml_db', github: 'jetthoughts/yaml_db', ref: 'fb4b6bd7e12de3cffa93e0a298a1e5253d7e92ba'
gem 'acts_as_follower'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.9.0'
gem 'impressionist'
gem 'youtube_it', github: 'jsh-c/youtube_it'
gem 'open_uri_redirections'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '2.7.0'
gem 'bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/jordanbrock/bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails.git', :branch => :rails4
gem 'axlsx_rails'
gem 'zip-zip'
gem 'to_csv-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/liangwenke/to_csv-rails.git'
gem 'newrelic_rpm', group: :production
gem 'seed-fu', '~> 2.3'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'tweetstream'
gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 4.0.0' # For 4.0.x
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: The gemfile doesn't really help in this case. It looks like you are missing a required asset (bg-text.png). Have you verified that this file is actually there? If not, make sure your local workspace has everything you need for this project.

Comment: I have no asset called bg-text.png and neither have I ever used it for this project. I dont even have any folders either in my repository called "sliders", "revolution" etc. I can find the line in the css script that directs to this asset. I have tried to comment it out or completely delete it but this didnt fix the problem either.

Comment: Since the file wasn't used, I deleted it and it fixed the issue. It also helped to delete the entire class using the asset.

Comment: I experience similar error too, from one page reload to other: once it is ok, other time I get an error, without having changed anything.